# Extract words before and after a specific word

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I need to extract words before and after a word like '%don%' in a ntext column.

`table A, column name: Text`

Example:
TEXT

`where it was done it will retrieve the...
at the end of the trip clare done everything to improve
it is the only one done in these times`

I would like the following results:

`was done it
clare done everything
one done in`

I am using T-SQL, Left and right functions did not work with ntext data type of the column containing text.

Comment: What if the text values has `don` within it more than once?

Comment: extract both. thanks

Comment: The first thing you need to do is stop using `ntext`. In fact, you should have stopped using it a long time ago, when SQL Server 2008 was released. You do that by using an `alter table` statement to alter the column to `nvarchar(max)`. Once that's done,  It's quite easy to use `charindex` or `patindex` to get the position of the delimiters, and then `substring` to extract the data between those delimiters.

Comment: Would it be possible to extract the don and 10 characters before and after it?

Comment: yes, it would be possible.

Comment: i was thinking: SUBSTRING([Text], CHARINDEX('don', [Text]), CHARINDEX('don', [Text]))    but i loose the text before done. any help with the query? Thank you!!!

Comment: You should probably use a table valued function to split by space and get reconstruct the data. Make sure to use a function that also returns the order of the words such as Jeff Moden's [DelimitedSplit8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)

Comment: So what would your expected result for the text `We don't take donut donations here` be?

Comment: take donut donations

Comment: the word before and after '%don%'

Comment: I would have thought you would want `we don't take`, `take donut donations` and `donut donations here` given that example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said, you can use a string splitting function to split out each word and then return those you require.  Using the previously linked `DelimitedSplit8K`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.DelimitedSplit8K
--===== Define I/O parameters
        (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
--WARNING!!! DO NOT USE MAX DATA-TYPES HERE!  IT WILL KILL PERFORMANCE!
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 RETURN
--===== "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 1 up to 10,000...
     -- enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)
  WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "base" CTE and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter
                ),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(--==== Return start and length (for use in substring)
                 SELECT s.N1,
                        ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
                   FROM cteStart s
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
   FROM cteLen l
;
go

declare @t table (t ntext);
insert into @t values('where it was done it will retrieve the...'),('at the end of the trip clare done everything to improve'),('we don''t take donut donations here'),('ending in don');

with t as (select cast(t as nvarchar(max)) as t from @t)
    ,d as (select t.t
                 ,case when patindex('%don%',s.Item) > 0 then 1 else 0 end as d
                 ,s.ItemNumber as i
                 ,lag(s.Item,1,'') over (partition by t.t order by s.ItemNumber) + ' '
                  + s.Item + ' '
                  + lead(s.Item,1,'') over (partition by t.t order by s.ItemNumber) as r
           from t
               cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(t.t, ' ') as s
          )
select t
      ,r
from d
where d = 1
order by t
        ,i;
```

Output:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
|                            t                            |           r           |
+---------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
| at the end of the trip clare done everything to improve | clare done everything |
| ending in don                                           | in don                |
| we don't take donut donations here                      | we don't take         |
| we don't take donut donations here                      | take donut donations  |
| we don't take donut donations here                      | donut donations here  |
| where it was done it will retrieve the...               | was done it           |
+---------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
```

And a working example:

http://rextester.com/RND43071

Comment: Is there something easier that this like:

Comment: Select CONCAT(RIGHT(LEFT([Text], CHARINDEX('don', [Text])-1), 12)

Comment: No, because you may have multiple instances of `don` in the text string.  Trying to make your method work will only work for the first instance and ignore the rest.